# L.Control.Search for filtered marker with multiple layer

Tags: leaflet, javascript, filter, search

I have two geojson layer. tram.js and ubahn.js, both with just marker, I use them in a filter and want to search for these filtered marker. But it isn't working and I don't get any errors.

I used this Plugin: https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/master/examples/multiple-layers.html

This is it working: https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/multiple-layers.html

```
  var ubahn = {"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
       "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          7.000036,
          51.4452814
        ]
      },
        "name": "Planckstraße",
        "iconcategory": "ubahn"
      }
    },
```

And

```
var tram = {"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Dellwig Bahnhof",
        "iconcategory": "tram"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          6.9251056,
          51.4877009
        ]
      }
    },
```

And this is my code to filter my marker:

```
    let checkboxstatus

        var geojsonLayer = L.geoJSON(null, {
        filter: (feature) => {
           const isLineChecked = checkboxstatus.lines.includes(feature.properties.line)
        // CODE OF A WORKING FILTER
},


onEachFeature: function forEachFeature (feature, layer) {
                var popupContent = feature.properties.name;
            if(feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
                } layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
            },

            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.marker(latlng, {
                    icon: L.divIcon({
                        className: feature.properties.iconcategory,
                        html: feature.properties.iconcategory[0].toUpperCase(),
                        iconSize: L.point(25, 25),
                    })
                })

                  .bindTooltip(feature.properties.name);
            }
        }).addTo(map);
function updatecheckboxstatus() {
        checkboxstatus = {
        lines: [],
            // MORE CODE
        }

        for (let input of document.querySelectorAll('input')) {
            if (input.checked) {
                switch (input.className) {
                    case 'line': checkboxstatus.lines.push(input.value); break
                    // AND MORE CODE
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (let input of document.querySelectorAll('input')) {
        //Listen to 'change' event of all inputs

        input.onchange = (e) => {
            geojsonLayer.clearLayers()
            updatecheckboxstatus()
            geojsonLayer.addData([ubahn, tram])
        }
    }


    /****** INIT ******/
    updatecheckboxstatus()
    geojsonLayer.addData([ubahn, tram]);
```

And now, I thought I could add the search function and use the `geojsonLayer`

```
    /*
    var markerSuche = new L.geoJson([
       geojsonLayer, geojsonOpts          
    ]);
    markerSuche.addTo(map); */

    var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
        layer: geojsonLayer,
        propertyName: 'name',
        container: 'findbox',
        textPlaceholder: 'Suche',
        collapsed: false,
        marker: false,
        moveToLocation: function (latlng) {
            console.coordinates(latlng);
            map.setView(latlng, 12); // set the zoom
        }
    });

    map.addControl(searchControl);
```

Is it possible, what I had in my head? Did I just miss a ; or ) somewhere? Using the `markerSuche` layer ( in /* */) isn't working as well. Do I need `markerSuche`? Where is my mistake? I just want to search for the marker in my filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from `ubahn` GeoJSON properties being a bit mangled and both features missing `line` property, it's hard to say why above code doesn't work for you.

Code below (ES5 syntax) worked for me:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<input type="checkbox" class="line" value="Line1"> Line 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="line" value="Line2"> Line 2<br>

<script>

var ubahn = {"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "Planckstraße",
    "iconcategory": "ubahn",
    "line": "Line1"
  },
   "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      7.000036,
      51.4452814
    ]
  }
}]};

var tram = {"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dellwig Bahnhof",
    "iconcategory": "tram",
    "line": "Line2"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      6.9251056,
      51.4877009
    ]
  }
}]};

var map = L.map('map', {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new L.latLng(51.4452814, 7.000036),
        layers: L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
    });


var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
  filter: function(feature) {
     var isOK = (checkboxstatus.lines.indexOf(feature.properties.line) >= 0);
     return(isOK);
  },  
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng).bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
    }
});

var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
  layer: geojsonLayer,
  propertyName: 'name',
  textPlaceholder: 'Suche',
  collapsed: false,
  marker: false,
  moveToLocation: function (latlng) {
    map.setView(latlng, 12);
  }
});

map.addControl(searchControl);

var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].onchange = function(e) {
    geojsonLayer.clearLayers();
    updatecheckboxstatus();
    geojsonLayer.addData([ubahn, tram]);
  }
}

var checkboxstatus;

function updatecheckboxstatus() {
  checkboxstatus = {
  lines: [],
  }
  var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      switch (input[i].className) {
        case 'line': checkboxstatus.lines.push(input[i].value); break
      }
    }
  }
}
updatecheckboxstatus();

</script>
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid. When I use your code I get an error from Chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`.

Comment: You mean you just copied the whole code and it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes. I just get the map and the checkboxes.

Comment: Did you try to check/select the checkboxes? Initially nothing is selected/displayed.

Comment: Yes, checked and unchecked - nothing is happening. In Firefox the error says: `TypeError: e is undefined`. And Safari says: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.indexOf')`.

Comment: Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/5ncepoLw/

Comment: I'm offended and feel mobbed. Used your code, used your sources, still the same error. Tested my code from above in this fiddle thing. It's working. Looks like, my professor is getting a fiddle link.

Comment: Weird are the ways of modern software tools ...